# Can a Lightsaber cut through Laminanium?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Can a Lightsaber cut through [Laminanium](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Laminanium)?

The Wikia article doesn't seem to address that, it merely says Jedi's new armour (Jedi expeditionary suit) was made of it in latter-period EU/Legends novels.

<sub>Obviously, an answer from EU/Legends is OK.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, but with difficulty.

From the [*Legacy of the Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force) series by Troy Denning, book 6 page 21 (emphasis mine):

> Ben ignited his lightsaber then rolled to his feet, Force-sprang to the droid’s side, and swung at its cannon arm. **The laminanium was so strong that his first strike cut only halfway through.** The Guardian spun toward him, its other arm coming around like a club, its fingers spraying flechettes in random directions.
>
> Ben stepped after the cannon arm and swung again, using the Force to guide his blow. **He felt his lightsaber sink into the same cut as before and slice through**, then turned toward the other arm and attacked the flechette-spraying hand at the wrist.

And from [*The Swarm War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Swarm_War), also by Troy Denning:

> Luke had no choice but to block with his blade, and no place to block but the forearm. Raynar's lightsaber went spinning off, still securely in the grasp of his three-fingered hand, and caught one of Luke's bugcrunchers squarely in the back. **The weapon sliced through six centimeters of laminanium armor** before the severed forearm flew free. The blade deactivated, and the hilt disappeared into the tangle of death and destruction at the droid's feet.

Getting even lower down the canon scale, we have the following from [Star Wars Role-playing Games](http://starwarsrp.net/topic/53701-hadzuska-misinis-shadows-skin/):

> Laminanium-iron alloy plaiting can withstand blaster fire, and a single glancing blow from a lightsaber.