# Is there any material which cannot be cut by a lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In all the Star Wars movies till now we can see many Jedi & Dark Side characters using various types & colors of lightsabers. As per the movies, lightsabers can cut through everything & anything.

So my question is, in the Star Wars movies is there anything mentioned about a material that cannot be cut by a lightsaber?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Would a lightsaber cut through wood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12012/31394) and [Can a Lightsaber cut through Laminanium?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111271/31394)

Comment: If sheilds count as a material -  in Ep1 Kenobi and Qui-Gon bail against the droidekas instead of simply deflecting all of the blaster bolts and stabbing through the shielding

Comment: Now I don't know much bout star wars but I thought I remembered pretty clearly in episode 8 the fight against snoke's guards and the guards had lightsaber-proof arm guards?

Comment: I don't remember precisely, hence I don't provide an answer, but I think in the tome 2 of the Darth Bane trilogy, he found an armor that is a living form and can "parry" almost anything, including lightsaber hit.

Comment: They reflect fire from energy weapons instead of cutting it.  makes me wonder though--if you fired a big enough bullet at a Jedi and they tried to deflect it, would it simply cut the bullet allowing the two halves to continue past and hit the Jedi?

Comment: They can't cut through other lightsabers, so there's that.

Comment: @Neyt, they were called orbelisks or something along those lines. He found out later that they’re not huge fans of electricity

Answer (score 153, accepted):

In the movies, what lightsabers can cut through seems to be, at best, a mixed bag. Focusing on the earlier movies, IV, V, & VI, where the technology is first introduced, I looked at two major encounters.

Here, in the [Cloud City duel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgyitSlMtMY), we can see that neither Luke's not Vader's weapons can cut through other lightsabers (obviously). We can also see that neither can cut through various pieces of metal: railings, floor decking, random mechanical~electrical housings ripped from the walls.  However, they can cut through coolant gas conduit piping.

Here, in the [Throne Room duel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1MnMA0TzGI), we can likewise see that floor decking and machine housings are lightsaber impervious.  However, sometimes railings and decking *can* be cut, as when Vader throws his saber and brings down the catwalk with Luke on it. However, just a couple minutes later, after Vader finds out about Leia, neither Luke nor Vader can do more than elicit a few sparks from any of those computer terminals, support columns, gangways or stairs. Even though Luke is now pretty emotional, that doesn't seem to affect his lightsaber power output. In fact, their saber cuts just bounce right off the railings! Sometimes without even a spark. It's not until the climactic strike where Luke severs Vader's hand that his lightsaber is able to break through the railing, leaving jagged ends behind. Even there, I'm not convinced that the lightsaber did the damage: this was where Luke was bashing Vader's arm against the railing, clearly weakening it. I think the railing just broke from excess stresses placed on it.

A brief survey of later movies reveals similar limitations. Neither Dooku nor Obi-Wan can seem to put a scratch in the floor, for example.

**Conclusion:** Lightsabers can only and always cut precisely what is needed to be cut for the narrative purposes of the screenwriter & special effects folk.

Comment: So what you're saying, is that light sabres are nice narrative knives?  That their ability to cut is... hand waved?  That they are, in truth, literal plot devices?

Comment: Lightsabers cut with the strength of plot. *(With apologies to Gene Roddenberry.)*

Comment: Mind that a light saber doesn’t actually cut but *melts* (when it doesn’t vaporize) the materials it has contact to. This implies that the effect is stronger, the longer the material is exposed to the plasma, so faster swipes could indeed cause less damage. It’s also possible that metallic materials have a deflecting effect on the magnetic field, which requires a certain minimum strength towards the surface, as otherwise the plasma doesn’t even touch it. Of course, I still don’t believe that the movies are consistent in that regard and none answers, where the plasma goes when it doesn’t cut…

Comment: In the prequels, Darth Maul's lightsaber sparks against the hole in which Obiwan had fallen.  It sparked, but didn't appear to otherwise have any effect on the hole's edge.

Comment: IMO this answer is more about fight choreography and special effects than it is about canon. It seems to be possible for lightsabers to glance off surfaces, usually causing sparks, without cutting through them, but I don't think there's anything in those scenes the lightsabers canonically couldn't cut through.

Comment: Lightsabers need to be held against doors for a period of time in order to cut through them, so it appears there is a threshold of energy that needs to be applied by the lightsaber in order to cut through things. That threshold may be high for some material (floors, doors), and low for others (ghost cloaks, hands).

Comment: didn't finn take a hit to the head in his fight with kylo ren in episode 9, and get off with a non-fatal wound? so add finn's head to the list of things that are impervious to lightsabers.

Comment: Yeah indeed. It's Star Wars. Attachment to consistency is not that much of a priority, not even on original trilogy.

Answer (score 33):

Beyond other lightsabers, off the top of my head I can think of two instances in the movies of a weapon capable of blocking lightsaber blades.

The first is in *Revenge of the Sith*. Obi-Wan Kenobi and Anakin Skywalker battle against Grevious' guards. The guards use an electrostaff that is clearly shown to block the lightsabers of Kenobi and Skywalker. The electrostaff's material appears to be called [Phrik](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Phrik).

The second is in *The Force Awakens*. Finn faces off against a stormtrooper nicknamed TR-8R (officially FN-2199). At that point in the movie, Finn is using the Skywalker lightsaber, while the trooper uses his "Z6 riot control baton". We see several blows connect, which confirms the baton is lightsaber resistant. However, I couldn't find a name for the material of the riot control baton.

Outside of the movie realm, the videogame *Jedi: Fallen Order* features similar weapons, with similar capabilities. It tends to confirm those weapons aren't unique.

---

In line with the conclusion in [elemtilas' answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227483/117451), the simple explaination is likely that the film/game makers simply needed to come up with a cool weapon to put in a lightsaber duel without turning everybody into a Jedi.

Comment: I'd say that the Riot control batons would be based very very closely off of the Magna Guards staffs. They even function more or less the same, are both nonlethal etc.
Also It'd be a too massive leap for Disney Star Wars to invent something actually new

Comment: You have to take into consideration the skill of the user. It's like wielding a katana blade, if you have to cut a bamboo tree at your first lesson, you will not be able, but master swordsmen would be able to cut ~20 bamboo sticks in a swing

Comment: @RigaCrypto Obi-Wan and Anakin have fought a war lightsaber in hand for three years, and Finn clearly has had training in melee combat, so it's nobody's first lesson. Furthermore, it's not a katana, it's a magic spacesword. It's kinda the schtick that it cuts through stuff effortlessly.

Comment: @AmiralPatate Ofc, but Finn hasn't handled a lightsaber in his life and I would be scared AF to fight with something like that for the first time. It was just a point, not necessarily a conclusion :)

Comment: @Hobbamok For a series that screams about letting the past die so much, you'd think they would stop bringing back every reference possible...

Answer (score 20):

I don't know which material it was made of but the blast doors in *Star Wars I: Phantom Menace* are more or less impervious to the light sabers:

> Blast doors were extra doors that were closed next to a room's regular entrance or other closed door to provide extra reinforcements against hostile forces such as explosives, powerful blasters, or even lightsabers.
>
> From the Legends Wookieepedia Article on [Blast Doors](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blast_door/Legends)

However, as we see in the same film, Qui-Gon cannot cut through the blast door but has to melt through:

I don't know if you count Beskar, which appears in *Mandalorian* and other SW-series to be relevant to your question:

> Beskar was one of the toughest and most legendary metals in the galaxy. The alloy could withstand direct blaster fire and was capable of repelling the strikes of a lightsaber. The metal could also be reforged to any warrior's liking.
>
> From the Canon Wookieepedia Article on [Beskar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beskar)

However, *Exar Kun* was able to cut through Beskar:

> Mandalorians furnished starships and constructed weapons with beskar, while the Jedi Master Arca Jeth utilized a heavy slab of Mandalorian iron to seal the tomb of the deceased Sith Lord Freedon Nadd on Dxun. The beskar door proved an impediment for the Dark Jedi Exar Kun, who was shocked to find that his lightsaber was rebuffed by the Mandalorian iron, and only gained access to the blocked tomb with repeated strikes of his saber at its highest power output.
>
> From the Legends Wookieepedia Article on [Beskar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_iron)

So, with Beskar being officially one of the toughest material in the *Star Wars Universe* and a lightsaber being able to cut through, there is probably *no material that is totally impervious* to lightsabers. However, as we see in the *Phantom Menace*, there are materials even a lightsaber cannot simply cut through. With enough time, it would seem like everything can be gone through with a lightsaber.

---

In Legends, there are materials that can block a lightsaber. Not directly a material but metal enhanced by [Sith Alchemy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_alchemy/Legends)

> Sith swords were constructed through various metallurgical and arcane means, transmuting base metals into an alchemical alloy possessing an unusual affinity for dark side energies. The rare metallic compounds used in its construction could result in blades varying in weight from 3 kilograms up to 6.5 kilograms, a blade far heavier than its 1.4 meter length[source?] would indicate. It often required great strength of body as well as in the Force to successfully wield the weapon and make it as dangerous as a lightsaber. In fact, **the alchemical alterations allowed the Sith sword to block incoming lightsaber attacks**, as well as deflect and redirect blaster bolts in much the same way a lightsaber did.
>
> From the [Sith Swords](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_sword) article on Wookieepedia

If *block* means it's totally impervious to lightsabers or simply can resist it for a short time before the lightsaber melting through, I don't know.

Comment: The question is about the MOVIES. In both Legends and Disney canon, there are several examples of materials that can withstand lightsabers (Beskar, Cortosis, etc). But in the MOVIES, there is no such material mentioned.

Comment: Even in Legends, while several materials can *resist* lightsaber attacks, to varying degrees, I don't remember any of them ever having been conclusively established to be impervious to lightsabers, outright. That is, while a suit of Beskar armor might deflect a lightsaber swing and prevent you getting cut in half, it's less clear whether a lightsaber-wielder at their leisure to take a bunch of time working on a Beskar plate in calm circumstances, wouldn't eventually be able to slowly erode it away and eventually completely cut through.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for pointing this out. I was probably too eager to answer and didn't read the question precisely enough. I only had time now to improve my answer and have done so.

Answer (score 17):

In *The Clone Wars* Season 2 Episode 18 "The Zillo Beast" Anakin Skywalker encounters a gigantic creature which is the episode's namesake.  He is quite surprised to find that the hard scales which cover its body are completely impervious to his lightsaber.

A TV show is like a movie.

Comment: I have some clips of these scenes in my answer below, along with some extra information if anyone is curious

Answer (score 9):

In the *Star Wars* EU: Cortosis blades, made of Cortosis, could enhance weapons to make them resistant to lightsabers. Some variants with high purity materials could short out a light sabre for limited periods.

Not in the movies though.

Answer (score 5):

YES! In Canon, Star Wars Clone Wars, an animated episode depicted the Zillo Beast:

[The Zillo Beast, an Unbreakable Creature](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zillo_Beast)

It originates from [Malastare](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Malastare)

> Its heavy plated armor was invulnerable to explosions, blaster fire, and even **lightsaber strikes.** Jedi Knight Anakin Skywalker discovered that gaps in the creature's armored plates could be exploited to damage or stun the creature.

During the episode, the Jedi knights attempted to pierce the armor of it, but it did absolutely no damage. It didn't even leave a mark.

See this clip of Anakin's Lightsaber doing nothing: [Clip of "The Zillo Beast"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOa5I.jpg)

---

> The Zillo Beast appeared in the episodes "The Zillo Beast" and "The Zillo Beast Strikes Back" from the Star Wars: The Clone Wars television series.

Originally, The Emperor requested that they should clone the beast in hopes of creating new armor using the skin, but as far as I've heard, the show has yet to use it anywhere.

See this clip of him ordering the cloning: [Clip of "The Zillo Beast Strikes Back"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvQG.jpg)

The Force Deities were also untouchable by lightsabers. They could wield the pure energies of the force, basically making them invulnerable to lightsabers and any other force-based ability.

Comment: Lets all just happen to notice that if the cloning had been successful, perhaps clone troopers wouldn't just be "bucket heads" who's armor did nothing.

Comment: The question is about the movies specifically, also note this has already been included in another answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I answered before that one was posted, it took a while to capture the clips. Henceforth why his was answered first, furthermore, my answer includes direct links to footage and the wiki link plus extra information. Need anything else?

Comment: *it took a while to FIND and CAPTURE the clips* my bad.

Comment: A six hour gap is quite significant hence my comment. However, the main point is that the question is scoped to the movies and your answer is about one of the TV series.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot There is less of a scenario for the movies.

This TV Series IS STILL CANON. So its in the same universe, meaning it comes from the movies too.

Besides, they are all from the same plotline/timeline, whether its a movie or tv show is irrelevant.

Comment: Sure they are all from the same universe and are all canon. That doesn't change the fact that the question is specifically scoped to the movies. (Not that it matters mind, this question has ridden the HNQ train hard so the votes are all over the place).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot He did not mention we could NOT use tv shows, and besides the point, movies and tv shows are the same thing, IE, a TV Show is just a movie cut up into pieces, and MUCH longer.

They are both videos, they are both canon, are both in the same story. Not much else to say

Comment: Well you're arguing semantics here and looking for wording that isn't there to make an argument. In either case it doesn't really matter now as most of the answers aren't about the films as requested anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[Beskar steel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beskar), prominently seen in *The Mandalorian*, is said to be so tough it resists attacks from blasters and lightsabers, which is why Mandalorians go to such lengths to (re-)aquire it and forge armor and weapons out of it.

Answer (score 0):

From the books, specifically the Jedi Academy series, the [Fireworm](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fireworm) has a crystalline skin that makes it impervious to being sliced by a lightsaber.

Comment: Not that the question is about the movies.

Comment: Indeed, in the books there are many materials that can go toe-to-toe with lightsaber plasma; Cortosis, or any other plasma blade like a Vibro blade, etc.

Comment: I dont believe this is canon, legends is just lore

Comment: @TaylorS Yes, though Disney has brought up lots of stuff from Legends canon into Disney canon as they have seen fit. It's quite possible they'll add Fireworms to Disney canon some time in the future.

Comment: @TylerH I find it a bit hard to believe, theyre done with the main series, and the mandalorian is more focused on its own series now.

I doubt they'd just pull up an old entity from legends and throw it into the mandalorian.

Comment: Who said anything about The Mandalorian television show? Disney canon encompasses all Star Wars movies, many books, comics, several TV shows, and more, including any *future* works (they already have two more movies in pre-production), as I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Another lightsaber.

It can essentially cut any material but a lightsaber. It itself is nothing, it’s energy from a crystal, but one lightsaber cannot go through another lightsaber which is essentially nothing but energy, interesting.

Answer (score -1):

A lightsaber, regardless of the name appears to be made of plasma isolated in some kind of magnetic field, any material with a melting point higher than the temperature of the "blade" will remain intact. 
Star Trek has a plasma cutter that is in every starfleet engineers toolkit for general maintenance, with much the same effect as a lightsaber.

Comment: well science usually doesnt make any sense here.

The force deities bypassed the laws and literally wield the energy which emits from the blades with their hands.

If it was just some basic plasma, surely it would burn them, they are still living creatures.

Comment: I think its more like, perhaps some kind of Physical force energy, similar to the first lightsaber, who's blade was made almost entirely of kyber crystals, which could clear cut through entire planets and galaxies. No way thats just some plasma

Comment: The user is probably protected by both the magnetic containment that is probably in a way keeping a layer of cold charged particles around the layer of hot charged particles in order to keep the surrounding air cold. As for the grip, it is probably made of an extremely low thermal conductive ceramic that appears to be metal.

Comment: Lightsabers are, in fact, magnetically confined lasers, not plasma. Whether they are standard lasers, as in our laser pointers, or (more likely, due to their kyber crystals) Force-enhanced lasers, they are still just lasers, not plasma like the "lasers" fired throughout the Star Wars universe. Lasers are light, or electromagnetic radiation, which allows the magnetic field to confine its length.